# I can't connect to QM of IBM MQ ERROR 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq, spring-jms

i have 2 QMs first is for testing and the second for real working and they have same properties, and the client, which can connect to those QMs. 
The problem is that i can't connect to the second one. 
it shows error :

```
  2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED
```

Most answers of the problem is that to change some settings on the server side of QM, but what i can to do if i dont have any access to the server of QM?

I mean that i have only client at all. Also i know that QM is working good with another client with the same credentials.

I have no idea to solve this problem with no access to the server side.

Comment: Someone with access will need to look at the server side AMQERR01.LOG.

Comment: The reason to check the AMQERR01.LOG on the queue manager is that the 2035 on the app side could be caused by at least three different things on the queue manager side (1. Missing OAM permissions, 2. CHLAUTH blocking the connection, 3. CONNAUTH failing to authenticate the user).  Without knowing which one is causing the issue it is hard to provide any troubleshooting help.

Comment: Thx for responce, i understand that it really hard to test if there is no log information. The problem is that i have some legacy code on java 6 or 7 and there the app connects to the same QM with the same credentials without any frameworks and it works. i can't understand why?

Comment: You stated you had two queue managers and the client that can connect to the first can not connect to the second.  So there must be a difference in the second queue managers configuration if the client side is the same in either case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem on a just installed IBM MQ server on Linux Ubuntu(only one local queue manager).
It was not production. One of the way to solve the problem is to disable the security (not to do in production).

```
ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
```

**It is a command you run on the server.**

Please read [queue manager RC 2035 MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/wmq-71-75-80-90-queue-manager-rc-2035-mqrcnotauthorized-or-amq4036-or-jmswmq2013-when-using-client-connection-mq-administrator)
More specifically paragraph 2.c.

> Disable the Channel Authentication Records feature
>
> ALTER QMGR CHLAUTH(DISABLED)
>
> WARNING: Disabling this new feature is not recommended for MQ 7.1
>   production queue managers due to security implications. Note that
>   disabling CHLAUTH results in a policy that accepts administrative
>   connections by default. The administrative effort to lock down
>   administrative access with CHLAUTH(DISABLED) is much greater than to
>   do so with CHLAUTH(ENABLED). It is therefore recommended to leave
>   CHLAUTH(ENABLED) and use the other security features of WebSphere MQ
>   V7.1 to authenticate administrator connections.